# Jenkins pipeline - Set environment variable in nodejs code

Tags: node.js, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline which is executing few nodejs files like below -

```
stage('validate_paramters') {
       steps {
               sh 'node ${WORKSPACE}/file1.js'
            }
        }
stage('test') {
        steps {
               sh 'node ${WORKSPACE}/file2.js'
            }
        }
```

How can I set variables in file1 which can be accessed inside file2? I tried below approach but its giving `undefined` as value -

file1.js -

```
process.env['OPERATIONS'] = "10"
```

file2.js -

```
var operations = process.env.OPERATIONS
```

Comment: They would need to be output to stdout from the first file.

Comment: Yeah we have tried the file option like write to a file from first js and read from there in second js file but wanted to check if there is a way to set the variables.

Comment: These are executed in different processes, so you would need some kind of controller or broker architecture otherwise.